# Connecting Jasmine spec file to my JS file

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write tests for my tic-tac-toe game.The errors says 'ReferenceError: CountClick is not defined', 'ReferenceError: Board is not defined'

My guess is that the TicTacToeSpec file is not reading in my TicTacToe.js file. How do I make them known to each other?

spec/javascripts/TicTacToeSpec.js

```
   describe('Count clicks', function() {                     
     it('adds 1 to counter when clicked', function() {       
       counter = 0;                                          
       CountClick();                                         
       expect(counter).toEqual(1);                           
     });                                                     
   });
```

/index.html

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src="TicTacToe.js"></script>
  <script src="spec/javascripts/TicTacToeSpec.js"></script>
```

/Gemfile

```
  gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'jasminerice'
```

/TicTacToe.js

```
 function CountClick() {
   counter++;
 };

 function Board() {
   this.initialBoard();
   this.newBoard();
   game.firstMove();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/tree/master/dist by Pivotal file structure and add the lib file to your own project with an index page similar to their own.

Comment: Link-only answer and it is no longer valid since the link target is gone. Can you update the link please, or delete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Both TicTacToe.js and TicTacToeSpec.js have to be included in your HTML test harness. The code you've posted isn't including TicTacToe.js. Your script includes should be:

```
<script src="path/to/TicTacToe.js"></script>
<script src="spec/javascripts/TicTacToeSpec.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah I should have added everything in my index page. TicTacToe.js is part of it.